# How to change focus to new HTML5 Canvas element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a bunch of canvas elements in my html file like so:

```
   <canvas id="one"></canvas>
   <canvas id="two"></canvas>
```

I'm using the arrow keys to move an object around `#one`, but I want to have that object "appear" in `#two` when it hits a point on `#one`, e.g. `x=150` and `y=55`.
I tried using the jQuery `focus()` method when that coordinate was triggered, but the object stayed in `#one`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a canvas element focus-able, and therefor able to capture key-strokes, you simply add a `tabIndex` attribute to the element:

Now you can <kbd>TAB</kbd> between the elements and bind event-listeners to the canvas element directly.

Inside the handler you simply draw to the canvas you want based on whatever criteria you require.

## Example

```js
var canvases = document.querySelectorAll("canvas"),
    i = 0; 

while(canvas = canvases[i++]) {
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.tabIndex = 0;
  canvas.addEventListener("keyup", process);
}

function process(e) {
  var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 150);
  ctx.fillText("KEY HERE: " + e.keyCode, 10, 10);
}
```

```css
canvas {border:1px solid #999;margin:0 2px 2px 0; display:inline-block}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing focus when that coordinate is hit, I think you need to change the `<canvas>` element (and associated context) you're drawing to, e.g.:

```
    var theCanvas = document.getElementById("one");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

    ... your canvas drawing code here ...

    if (posX < 150 && posY < 55) {
        //clear the top canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        // switch to the second canvas
        theCanvas = document.getElementById("two");
        context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    }
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLfrbdun/) that borrows code from [rectangleworld.com](http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/15). Drag the circle into the upper left corner of the top canvas, and it should appear in the lower canvas.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLfrbdun/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as focus on a canvas for this purpose.

Your both canvases need to listen for keypresses, while your code needs to decide what to draw on which canvas.

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("one");
var context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("two");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

canvas1.width = canvas1.height = canvas2.width = canvas2.height = 50;

var obj = {x: 5, y: 5, w: 5};

function draw() {
  canvas1.width = canvas2.width = canvas2.width;
  context1.beginPath();
  context1.rect(obj.x, obj.y, obj.w, obj.w);
  context1.fillStyle = 'green';
  context1.fill();
  context2.beginPath();
  context2.rect(obj.x - canvas1.width, obj.y, obj.w, obj.w);
  context2.fillStyle = 'blue';
  context2.fill();
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  if(++obj.x > canvas1.width + canvas2.width) obj.x = 5;  
  draw();
});

draw();
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<canvas id="one"></canvas>
 <canvas id="two"></canvas>
<p>Click inside this window to get focus and then <br>press any key to move the object to the right</p>
```

Of course, this can be optimized not to redraw both canvases on each tick, but you get the idea.